# Docker compose error while creating mount source path

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created a docker-compose.yml using cloudestuary. After downloading it and putting it in my Laravel project folder and running docker-compose up -d the download takes place and then I get this message:

> ERROR: for worker-1  Cannot start service worker-1: error while creating mount source path '/var/www/html/lensin/html': mkdir /var/www: read-only file system
>
> ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: error while creating mount source path '/var/www/html/lensin/html': mkdir /var/www: read-only file system
>
> ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: error while creating mount source path '/var/www/html/lensin/html': mkdir /var/www: read-only file system
>
> ERROR: for workspace  Cannot start service workspace: error while creating mount source path '/var/www/html/lensin/html': mkdir /var/www: read-only file system
>   ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

I`m on Ubuntu 17, and have tried even to set 777 to all folders, and running it with sudo, but the result is the same. I have also tried to move the file and to edit the volumes in yml.

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        image: 'cloudestuary/nginx:mainline-fpm'
        restart: always
        environment:
            CLIENT_MAX_BODY_SIZE: 100m
            DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html/public
            INDEX_FILE: index.php
            PHP_FPM: app
        networks:
            - app
        volumes:
            - './html:/var/www/html'
        ports:
            - '80:80'
    app:
        image: 'cloudestuary/php-fpm:7.1'
        restart: always
        environment:
            MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE: 100m
            APP_URL: 'http://lensin.localhost'
            APP_KEY: 'base64:2X9U1HiBdmfbwvZ4UkwUP/25svg7439HXKWL1F8Xn1c='
            DB_CONNECTION: mysql
            DB_HOST: mysql
            DB_PORT: '3306'
            DB_DATABASE: cloudestuary
            DB_USER: cloudestuary
            DB_PASSWORD: secret
        networks:
            - app
        volumes:
            - './html:/var/www/html'
    workspace:
        image: 'cloudestuary/php-workspace:7.1'
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '2222:22'
        environment:
            MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE: 100m
            APP_URL: 'http://lensin.localhost'
            APP_KEY: 'base64:2X9U1HiBdmfbwvZ4UkwUP/25svg7439HXKWL1F8Xn1c='
            DB_CONNECTION: mysql
            DB_HOST: mysql
            DB_PORT: '3306'
            DB_DATABASE: cloudestuary
            DB_USER: cloudestuary
            DB_PASSWORD: secret
            SSH_PASSWORD: xsKEVWXPrdAeg
        networks:
            - app
        volumes:
            - './html:/var/www/html'
    worker-1:
        image: 'cloudestuary/php-cli:7.1'
        restart: always
        networks:
            - app
        environment: {  }
        volumes:
            - './html:/var/www/html'
        command: 'php artisan queue:work'
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:5.7'
        restart: always
        networks:
            - app
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_USER: cloudestuary
            MYSQL_DATABASE: cloudestuary
        volumes:
            - 'mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql'
volumes:
    mysql-data: {  }
networks:
    app: {  }
```

Comment: Looking for `read-only file system error in docker` might help

Comment: Check if using [`volume-nocopy`](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31792#issuecomment-286596588) helps or not

Comment: [Error creating aufs mount: read only file system](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20805) looks similar to your issue

Comment: Any fixes found for this issue?

Answer (score 66):

It's likely a pathing issue with Docker when installed with `snap`, you're better off installing it with the official documentation from Docker.

Remove docker from snap

```
snap remove docker
```

Remove the docker directory, and old version (It's okay if these don't exist already)

```
rm -R /var/lib/docker

sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
```

Install the official docker package: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Update: Since posting this answer, I've learnt that tools installed using `snap` are installed in a sandbox with limited permissions outside of that sandbox. This is likely the cause as `docker` won't have access to the external filesystem from its isolated sandbox environment.

Comment: Despite this solution having no explanation as to why, this actually worked for me.  Able to mount /opt/xxx without the "error while creating mount source path" error.  How about explaining why this works?

Comment: @JasonMorgan Unfortunately I can't provide a detailed response as to the WHY in this case, in addition it was a while ago now. It may have been the fact that snap installs docker differently and has different file permissions than a classic apt-get install from the official package.

For me, this was basically just cleaning the slate and starting with a fresh official install of docker. Could it have simply just fixed a misconfiguration? Possibly.

Comment: snap was working just fine, i had provided bad path for docker to mount

Comment: @SadithaUdayanga's answer worked for me. just restart your docker with `sudo systemctl restart docker`. I don't know what causes the error yet

Comment: This mysterious answer worked for me. Use _snap remove **--purge** docker_ to skip saving the previous snapshot because that can take a long time.

Comment: This worked to me too!

Comment: Silly Ubuntu includes snap installed Docker by default (when using installer it installs that)

Answer (score 22):

Restart your docker service. Then the problem will solve.

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: in case of snap you have to `snap restart docker` to restart docker service. But it does not worked for me. Looks like snap has some permission problem with the path I wanted to use as volume. changed to another path and it worked.

Comment: In my case, I deleted a project before running a `docker-composer down`. Then I ran the `docker-composer up` command in a fork of the original repository (after recreating the directory). Seems that Docker didn't like it. It was OK after a `docker system prune` and restart.

Comment: In my case I'm running Docker Desktop (4.13.1) on Mac. Restarting Docker solved it.

Answer (score 2):

What led me here was the Kubernetes V1VolumeMount. When deploying my application I was getting the same error format:

```
ERROR: for <pod_name> Cannot start <service_name>: error while creating mount source path '<source_path>': mkdir <dir_path>: read-only file system
```

At the start I was thinking permissions error as well, hence the message is a bit misleading. I turned out that I was trying to mount something that didn't exist in the source image. Hence, my uneducated suggestion would be, verify that what you are trying to mount does exist, if it doesn't you probably don't need that mount path.

P.S. I saw that there wasn't an accepted answer, so I am hoping that my contribution is not causing unnecessary cluttering.

Comment: the same issue. I have a symbolic file which link to a not mounted external storage device. I fixed the issue after mounted the storage device manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Got this error but the issue was that the source path was a [symlink](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html). For some reason docker does not seem to like it, even after restarting the service.

Had to use a real path and then it worked just fine with `Docker version 20.10.8` installed with `snap`.

Answer (score 0):

For Docker on Windows 10, sometimes you have just to wait a while (1-5 min) before executing `docker-compose up` again.

Hope this will help someone else.

Comment: I get the error randomly, on different mounted files, but waiting does not solve it.