# Docker file File shares on Ubuntu host

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

Good morning,

I am currently try to figure out how I create File shares on Ubuntu as the host OS for docker. On Windows and OSX you can set up Filesharing as below:

[image: Filesharing on Windows]

I require access to the File share in my docker-compose as an example see below:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  node_gauc:
    image: node-g:v1
    ports:
      - "444:444" # https test port
    volumes: 
      - ./NodeServer/cert/https.crt:/usr/share/node/cert/https.crt
      - ./NodeServer/cert/key.pem:/usr/share/node/cert/key.pem
   build: 
     context: .
     dockerfile: ./NodeServer/dockerfile
   restart: unless-stopped
   container_name: node-g
```

If I don't have access when I build and start the container I get the following issues:

```
ERROR: for node-g  Cannot start service node_g: error while creating mount source path '/usr/share/t/work/6b37be0079afed03/NodeServer/cert/https.crt': mkdir /usr/share/t: read-only file system

ERROR: for node_g  Cannot start service node_g: error while creating mount source path '/usr/share/t/work/6b37be0079afed03/NodeServer/cert/https.crt': mkdir /usr/share/t: read-only file system
```

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

I am still unsure why its trying to create a directory but I suppose that is another matter.

Is it possible to create File share on a Ubuntu host server similar to what you can on OSX(Mac) or Windows OS?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You don't need to do anything.  The daemon runs natively on the Linux host and can directly access the entire host filesystem with no special setup.

Comment: Hmmm I must have an issue, with the actual host filesystem permission. I will look into it and see if I can resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo docker-compose up ` or otherwise adding your user to the docker group? Also, you can't use both build and image directives

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker compose error while creating mount source path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764477/docker-compose-error-while-creating-mount-source-path)

Comment: Apologies the issue was related to the Linux build and a issue with the Docker installation. The first comment from David is spot on you do not need to do anything. This question should be closed